# Does "Secret Life of Walter Mitty" have two endings?

Tags: ending, alternate-version, the-secret-life-of-walter-mitty

A while ago, I watched The Blu-Ray of Ben Stiller's "Secret Life of Walter Mitty" (2013), and I remember it ending as follows:

> Walter has the courage to ask out Cheryl, but she declines, because she is already in a relationship. He accepts this and moves on, and we see him meet another potential love interest. Changed by his experience, he has the confidence to talk to her.

However, I recently watched the movie on Netflix (Canada), and it had a different ending:

> Walter asks Cheryl to see his sister's Grease play, and Cheryl says yes. They are seen holding hands after they see that Walter is the "Quintessence of Life", and the movie then ends.

The ending I saw on Netflix can be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2i2G_jwXBg).

Am I confusing this with a different movie? Is the Mandela-Berenstain effect at play here? Or did the Blu-ray contain a different ending (or perhaps multiple endings) compared to what Netflix is showing?

Google has been no help, as most of the search results are about people writing alternate endings for school assignments.

Comment: I don't know about multiple endings, but Wikipedia seems to acknowledge the "holding hands" ending: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Secret_Life_of_Walter_Mitty_(2013_film)#Plot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have Walter Mitty on vudu, and it does not have the first ending you mention, only the second happier ending.  Interestingly, I can think of a movie that has the exact ending you mentioned, starring Brendan Fraser, called Bedazzled.  In it, the protagonist is in love with a woman from work, he is granted several wishes by Elizabeth Hurley as the Devil and all of them are based around this woman but go disastrously wrong, and in the end asks out his co-worker who politely declines as she is in a relationship.  The movie ends with him meeting a new neighbor that he begins dating.

Comment: I'm 99% sure that Bedazzled is the movie that I was thinking of, and I got the two of them confused in my mind. Thanks!

Comment: The first ending you describe also sounds like the ending of 500 Days of Summer.

Answer (score 7):

The website blu-ray.com has the most insane, indepth reviews of blu-rays you can find.  They do not list any alternate endings for [The Secret Life of Walter Mitty (2013)](http://www.blu-ray.com/movies/The-Secret-Life-of-Walter-Mitty-Blu-ray/79007/), but they do list "alternate scenes".

Digging a little deeper, I found a [review on High Def Digest](http://bluray.highdefdigest.com/10560/secret_mitty.html) that lists the deleted, extended and alternate scenes as:

> This part of the bonus materials is broken up into three separate
>   sections for each type of scene, and those scenes can be watched
>   individually or as a group. The Deleted Scenes section (7 ½ min.)
>   consists of 'Morning Routine' (2 min.); 'Young Odessa Fantasy' (1
>   min.); 'Jester Fantasy' (1 min.); 'Manfree Fantasy' (2 min.); and
>   'Impound Lot' (2 min.). The Extended Scenes section (4 ½ min.)
>   consists of 'Extended Arctic Fantasy (3 min.) and 'Christmas Walk' (2
>   min.). The Alternate Scenes section (4 min.) consists of 'Fly to
>   Greenland Alternate Music' (2 ½ min.) and 'Severance Package' (1
>   min.).

So, it appears as if you might have your movie endings mixed up.

For the record, I just watched the ending of the version I have and it ends with the Netflix Canada version you mentioned above, and I don't have Netflix and I don't live in Canada.  :o)

Comment: I call it Mandela effect ;), he must have shifted from one alternate universe to other and seen ending from both universe :)